oc_reverse_df command: "Error in `list_unchop()`: ! Can't combine `x[[1]]$oc_building` <integer> and `x[[1043]]$oc_building` <character>
I am using the oc_reverse_df command from the opencage package to reverse geocode i.e., get street address and county/state IDs from latitude and longitude.
I have used this before, without any issues. I am trying to get street addresses for a number of grain elevators that sell corn. I'd appreciate any feedback on this if possible. Thanks.
Sample code:
crn_elev_geocode3 <- oc_reverse_df(corn_elevators3, latitude = lat,  longitude = long, output = "all")
Output:
Retrieving results from OpenCage [\] 100% ETA:  0s Error in list_unchop(): ! Can't combine x[[1]]$oc_building<integer> andx[[1043]]$oc_building<character>. Runrlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

Well, we do not have corn_elevators3 and connot help. Add the output of dput(head(corn_elevators3)) to your question as text. This will increase your chances of getting an answer dramatically.
